# Quel pronom sujet pour se substituer à « cela » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

Cette question provient de la P181 dans *Advanced French Grammar* de V Mazet :

> When the subject pronoun is ça, you can't do a simple inversion. There are three possible forms for questions. Each belongs to a different level of language. Note that ça changes to cela for the "literary" level.

Exemple donné :  Cela ne vous dérange-t-**il** pas ? = *Does this not bother you ?*

Puisque Mazet n'a pas donné l'antécédent de « cela », son genre est inconnu. Ainsi, comment et pourquoi est-ce que « **il** » a été employé et non pas **elle** ? Peut-on employer n'importe lequel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Cela* est neutre, d’où l’utilisation du *il*.

Si l’on voulais désigner quelqu’un ou quelque chose de féminin, l’on utiliserai plutôt *celle-là* ; pour désigner un masculin, l’on emploie *celui-là*.

Answer (score 1):

La question contient, d'une certaine manière, sa réponse: lorsque quelque chose a un genre inconnu, il s'accorde (généralement) en français au masculin.